# Array ordering in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

Is there a way to work with C-ordered or non-contiguous arrays natively in Julia?
For example, when using NumPy, C-ordered arrays are the default, but I can initialize a Fortran ordered array and do computations with that as well.
One easy way to do this was to take the Transpose of a matrix.
I can also work with non-contiguous arrays that are made via slicing.
I have looked through the documentation, etc. and can't find a way to make, declare, or work with a C-ordered array in Julia.
The transpose appears to return a copy.

Does Julia allow a user to work with C-ordered and non-contiguous arrays?
Is there currently any way to get a transpose or a slice without taking a copy?

Edit: I have found how to do slicing.
Currently it is available as a different type called a SubArray.
As an example, I could do the following to get the first row of a `100x100` array `A`

```
sub(A, 1, 1:100)
```

It looks like there are plans to improve this, as can be seen in https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5513

This still leaves open the question of C-ordered arrays.
Is there an interface for C-ordered arrays?
Is there a way to do a transpose via a view instead of a copy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Naturally, there's nothing that prevents you from working with row-major arrays *as a chunk of memory*, and certain packages (like Images.jl) support arbitrary ordering of arbitrary-dimensional arrays.

Presumably the main issue you're wondering about is linear algebra. Currently I don't know of anything out-of-the-box, but note that matrix multiplication in Julia is implemented through a series of functions with names like `A_mul_B`, `At_mul_B`, `Ac_mul_Bc`, etc, where `t` means transpose and `c` means conjugate. The parser replaces expressions like `A'*b` with `Ac_mul_B(A, b)` without actually taking the transpose.

Consequently, you could implement a `RowMajorMatrix <: AbstractArray` type yourself, and set up special multiplication rules:

```
A_mul_B(A::RowMajorMatrix, B::RowMajorMatrix) = At_mul_Bt(A, B)
A_mul_B(A::RowMajorMatrix, B::AbstractArray) = At_mul_B(A, B)
A_mul_B(A::AbstractArray, B::RowMajorMatrix) = A_mul_Bt(A, B)
```

etc. In addition to these two-argument versions, there are 3-argument versions (like `A_mul_B!`) that store the result in a pre-allocated output; you'd need to implement those, too. Finally, you'd also have to set up appropriate `show` methods (to display them appropriately), `size` methods, etc.

Finally, Julia's `transpose` function has been implemented in a cache-friendly manner, so it's quite a lot faster than the naive

```
for j = 1:n, i = 1:m
    At[j,i] = A[i,j]
end
```

Consequently there are occasions where it's not worth worrying about creating custom implementations of algorithms, and you can just call `transpose`.

If you implement something like this, I'd encourage you to contribute it as a package, as it's likely that others may be interested.

Comment: Fantastic answer. That is exactly what I was looking for. Especially the part involving the matrix multiplication. I'm still new to Julia but I may look in to making that type once I am more familiar with the language. Thanks!

Comment: This response is almost 3 years old, and Julia's Array Meister Tim Holy now has some very nice new array types that can be used, to allow for row-major and 0-base (or any base!) arrays.