# Transpose matrix and keep column-major memory layout

Tags: julia

### Illustration of the problem: the row norms of a matrix

Consider this toy example where I compute the norms of all the columns of a random matrix M

```
julia> M = rand(Float64, 10000, 10000);

julia> @time map(x -> norm(x), M[:,j] for j in 1:size(M)[2]);
  0.363795 seconds (166.70 k allocations: 770.086 MiB, 27.78% gc time)
```

Then compute the row norms

```
julia> @time map(x -> norm(x), M[:,i] for i in 1:size(M)[1]);
  1.288872 seconds (176.19 k allocations: 770.232 MiB, 0.37% gc time)
```

The factor between the two executions is due (I think) to the memory layout of the matrix (column-major). Indeed the computation of the row norms is a loop on non-contiguous data, which leads to non-vectorized code with cache miss.
I would like to have the same execution time for both norms computations.

Is possible to convert the layout of `M` to row major to get the same speed when calculating the norms of the rows ?

### What did I try

I tried with `transpose` and `permutedims` without success, it seems that when using these functions the memory is now in row-major (so columns major of the original matrix).

```
julia> Mt = copy(transpose(M));

julia> @time map(x -> norm(x), Mt[j,:] for j in 1:size(M)[2]);
  1.581778 seconds (176.19 k allocations: 770.230 MiB)

julia> Mt = copy(permutedims(M,[2,1]));

julia> @time map(x -> norm(x), Mt[j,:] for j in 1:size(M)[2]);
  1.454153 seconds (176.19 k allocations: 770.236 MiB, 9.98% gc time)
```

I used `copy` here to try to force the new layout.

How can I force the column-major layout of the transposition, or the row-major layout of the original matrix ?

### EDIT

As pointed out by @mcabbott and @przemyslaw-szufel there was an error in the last code I showed, I computed the norms of the rows of `Mt` instead of the norms of the columns.

The test on the norms of columns of `Mt` give instead:

```
julia> Mt = transpose(M);
julia> @time map(x -> norm(x), M[:,j] for j in 1:size(M)[2]);
  1.307777 seconds (204.52 k allocations: 772.032 MiB, 0.45% gc time)

julia> Mt = permutedims(M)
julia> @time map(x -> norm(x), M[:,j] for j in 1:size(M)[2]); 
  0.334047 seconds (166.53 k allocations: 770.079 MiB, 1.42% gc time)
```

So in the end it seems that the `permutedims` stores in column-major, as it would be expected. In fact the Julia arrays are always stored in column-major. `transpose` is kind of an exception because it's a row-major `view` of a column-major stored matrix.

Comment: I just found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355981/array-ordering-in-julia) is related but it is quite old

Comment: I think all 4 of these compute the same result. The first two are identical bar timing noise, but `map(norm, eachcol(M))` will be quicker. Note that `copy(transpose(M))` is `permutedims(M)`, both return a new `Array` (which is always column-major) with the data moved, while `transpose(M)` is a wrapper, with row-major storage.

Comment: Relevant issues: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/34830 about `norm(A; dims)`, https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/38774 about `view(transpose(A), i,:)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here:

- you are incorrectly benchamrking your code - most likely testing compiled code in the first run and uncompiled code (and hence measure compile times) in the second run. You should always run `@time` twice or use BenchmarkTools instead
- your code is inefficient - does unnecessary memory copying
- type of M is unstable and hence measurement includes the time to find out its type which is not a case when you are normally running a Julia function
- you do not need to have a lambda - you can just parse the function directly.
- as mentioned by @mcabbott your code contains a bug and you are measuring twice the same thing.
  After cleaning out your code looks like this:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra, BenchmarkTools

julia> const M = rand(10000, 10000);

julia> @btime map(norm, @view M[:,j] for j in 1:size(M)[2]);
  49.378 ms (2 allocations: 78.20 KiB)

julia> @btime map(norm, @view M[i, :] for i in 1:size(M)[1]);
  1.013 s (2 allocations: 78.20 KiB)
```

Now the question about about data layout.
Julia is using a column-major memory layout. Hence the operations that work on columns will be faster than those that work on rows.
One possible workaround would be to have a transposed copy of `M`:

```
const Mᵀ = collect(M')
```

This requires some time for copying but allows you later to match the performance:

```
julia> @btime map(norm, @view Mᵀ[:,j] for j in 1:size(M)[2]);
  48.455 ms (2 allocations: 78.20 KiB)

julia> map(norm, Mᵀ[:,j] for j in 1:size(M)[2]) == map(norm, M[i,:] for i in 1:size(M)[1])
true
```

Comment: Thank you for all these optimizations to my code, and for the alternative way of transposing. Turn out it was a silly mistake in fact, but posting here made me learn many thing.

Answer (score 2):

You are wasting a lot of time on creating copies of each column/row when calculating the norms. Use `view`s instead, or better yet, `eachcol`/`eachrow`, which also do not allocate:

```
julia> M = rand(1000, 1000);

julia> @btime map(norm, $M[:,j] for j in 1:size($M, 2));  # slow and ugly
  946.301 μs (1001 allocations: 7.76 MiB)

julia> @btime map(norm, eachcol($M));  # fast and nice
  223.199 μs (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)

julia> @btime norm.(eachcol($M));  # even nicer, but allocates more for some reason.
  227.701 μs (3 allocations: 47.08 KiB)
```

Comment: I believe the difference is `@btime collect(eachcol($M));`, i.e. that broadcasting over a generator collects it first, while mapping collects only the answer.